# form submit verses button using ajax to pass data - one works the other does not

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I have two pieces of jquery code in flask.  One is working and the other is not.  I have a form and a button that both call the same function thru ajax.  Right now, they call the same function for trouble shooting purposes. The button works great.  The form is not working.  By working, I mean getting an alert.  I do not see any errors

HTML - for the button

```
<div>
  <button class="#" id="getData" type="button">Get Data</button>
</div>
```

HTML - for the form

```
<form class="#" action="#" id="dataForm">
   <div class="#">
      <input class="#" id="title" />
      <button class="#" type="submit">Submit</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

JQUERY for form and button

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#dataForm").submit(function(){
    // alert("in dataform submit")
    $.ajax({
       url: "/getData"
    })
    .success(function(data){
      alert(data);
    });
  });
  $('#getData').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "/getData"
    })
    .success(function(data){
      alert(data);
    });
   });
}); //end doc ready
```

PYTHON/Flask

```
@app.route('/getData', methods=['GET' , 'POST'])
def getData():
    return('in getData - from Flask')
```

If I remove the commented alert in the dataForm submit (jquery), I get that alert as expected.  So it is getting into the submit function.  It doesn't seem to be getting into the ajax.  I am expecting to get an alert with "in getData - from Flask
".  I get that with the button, but I am not getting that with the form.  The form is not submitting anything because I want to get the ajax (returning the data for the alert) to work first.  I am sure that it is something simple that I am missing or not understanding.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `<form>` tag you have to mention the method and action attributes properly like this :

```
<form class="#" action="/getData" id="dataForm" method="post">
```

Similarly it would be wise to mention type of ajax request like :

```
$.ajax({
        ...
       type:'POST'
       url: "/getData"
       ...
       ... 
    })
     ....
```

You can have ajax .post documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

***Also don't forget to add event.preventDefault() in your ajax call.***

Comment: Happy to help :)